# Criar permissões no django

Tags: python, django, template

estava tentando criar uma permissão para meu template mas não consegui. dei umas pesquisadas para saber como fazer e não estou tendo resultado. basicamente gostaria de uma permissão semelhante ao que o django tem por exemplo o o is_superuser.

no template eu posso definir que apenas super usuários podem visualizar o conteúdo.

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <p> Este código só pode ser visto por um super usuário.</p>
{% endif %}
```

este é o que eu uso para super usuários porem eu quero fazer um tipo específico de usuário exemplo:

```
class UserTecnico(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cpf = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=11,blank=True)
SEXO_CHOICES = (
('M', 'Maculino'),
('F', 'Feminino'),
)
sexo = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True,choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
is_pode_acessar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

por exemplo aqui eu tenho um usuário técnico com um campo booleano "is_pode_acessar" o default está True porem no template nada acontece.

```
    {% if UserTecnico.is_pode_acessar %}
       <p> Este código só pode ser visto por um usuário técnico.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

alguém pode me dizer como faço ?

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que definiste a relação `OneToOne` entre o `User` e o `UserTecnico` podes fazer a validação com:

```
{% if user.usertecnico.is_pode_acessar %}
    <p> Este código só pode ser visto por um usuário técnico.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Obrigado! vou tentar.

Comment: deu certo da forma que você sugeriu obrigado!

Comment: Ainda bem! Marca a resposta como certa para poder ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida. Obrigado

Comment: gostaria mas não tenho pontos para conseguir marcar :/